# Runtime complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: runtime, big-o

Given a and b, I'm asked to compute a^b with a runtime faster than O(b). I came up with:

```
if(b == 1) return a;
if(b % 2 == 0) 
    return findExp(a,b/2) * findExp(a,b/2);
else 
    return findExp(a,(b/2)+1) * findExp(a,b/2);
```

My question is, is the runtime complexity of this algorithm logarithmic time or polynomial time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is O(b) not logarithmic.

In this part of the code `return findExp(a,b/2) * findExp(a,b/2);` you are calling the same function which returns the same value two times. Basically, you are spending redundant time for the second call.

Mathematically, if T(b) represents time required for a^b according to your algorithm, it is `T(b) = T(b/2) + T(b/2)` where each term corresponds to each call. `T(b) = 2.T(b/2)`. Solve this recurrence and you will get T(b) in the order of b.

To make it logarithmic, just prevent that redundant call by storing the value in a variable.

The edited code :

```
if(b == 1) return a;
if(b % 2 == 0) 
    int x = findExp(a,b/2);
    return x*x;
else 
    int x = findExp(a,b/2);
    return a*x*x;
```

Now `T(b) = T(b/2)` since you are calling findExp(a,b/2) only once (either in `if` part or in `else` part).

This gives you `O(log(b))` algorithm

If you wanna test it, run your code and the one mentioned by me for some large b, let us say b = 1000000000 and contrast the times taken.

Answer (score -1):

It is O(log(b)), so it is logarithmic.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why it isn't 2^(log b)?

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer. Consider adding an example to prove you are right.